# Is there an API to inspect the heap index file created by the sosex.bhi command?

Tags: windbg, sosex

Ultimately, I want to dump the heap data into a SQL Server database in order to be able to analyse it at ease.

Right now my approach is to run the `sosex.dumpgen` command while redirecting to a file and then dumping into the database using a small C# program. But it does not help me if I want to know what object referenced what. So, I have the `sosex.refs` command for that, but it does not lend itself very well to bulk analysis.

Steve Johnson's blog (http://www.stevestechspot.com/default.aspx) does not seem to suggest there is such an API.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such API. Someday, I hope to make sosex open source, but my day job does not allow time for that at present.

Comment: Is there something anyone could help you with?

Comment: Yes, but I would need to put in a bit of time to make it ready even for that. The code has grown so much over time and has been hacked to make it support all runtimes since 2.0 that it's a bit of a mess. Can I contact you for help, if needed?

Comment: I am not sure I am qualified enough to help, but who knows - mark dot kharitonov at gmail dot com.

Comment: Thanks for the offers of help.